# "Unable to save Stock Item issue" when I try to create multi-able simple products via RESTful API

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

I m using Magento2 API to create a configurable product, So I need to create numbers of the simple products first, but wired thing happened, some of the products have successfully created, but most of them failed.

the errs message is {message: "Unable to save Stock Item"}

some people could help??